# Correct way to merge branch into local branch

Tags: git, github

#### Setup

I have two local branches of `master`, called `foo` and `bar`.

First, I created the `foo` branch, made some changes/commits, and then pushed to a same-named branch on `origin` (GitHub repo).  I then created a pull request on GitHub for those changes to be merged into `master` there, and it is currently awaiting code review.

Afterwards, I created the `bar` branch, made some changes/commits, and then ran into a situation where I need to make more changes that depend on things that were added in the `foo` branch.

#### Question

Should I merge `remotes/origin/foo` into local `bar`?  Or should I merge local `foo` into local `bar` (or would that accomplish the same thing when no other commits have been made)?  Or is there another way entirely?

Basically, I'm just trying not to mess up history or cause unnecessary conflicts when I push `bar` and submit its PR. 
 I'm basically a complete git newbie, and have been using [this online book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2) as my learning resource, though I can't seem to find the answer there, and haven't had much luck Googling around.

Comment: If you can wait for `foo`s approval, you would not need to do any additional updates from it. Also at this point, `origin/foo` and `foo` should be at the same commit, otherwise your PR may be missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you're done editing your foo branch, you can just rebase your bar branch on top of foo

`git checkout bar`
`git rebase foo`

This will make bar have all the changes foo has.

Note that if you submit bar for a pull request BEFORE you've successfully merged in foo, bar is going to contain all the commits that is on `foo`, so it will "look" larger in terms of # of commits.

Just be sure to merge in `foo` first.  Once done most git platforms detect that commits in the other branch exist in the branch you're merging to (in this case, master), and get updated automatically.

Comment: The maintainer is out of town for like a week, and I need to submit the `bar` PR before the `foo` PR will be reviewed.  If I rebase like you're talking about, will that break anything?  I don't mind if it "looks" larger, as long as that's the only problem.  I just don't want the PRs to break things when the maintainer is able to merge them eventually.

Comment: It won't break anything.  For the sake of your reviewers though, let them know what you did.  That way they're not reviewing `foo` commits on the `bar` branch.  Put a comment saying you had to rebase off of `foo`.  That way they don't go review `foo`, then re-review the same commits in `bar`

Comment: Also wanted to point out that if at anytime you go change `foo`, you would need to again rebase `bar` back on top of `foo`, otherwise you'll likely hit a merge conflict.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you need to do is rebase `bar` on top of `foo`.

Requiring something from `foo` means `foo` needs to be merged before `bar` anyway, although the diff from `bar` will contain the `foo`'s changes until `foo` is merged.